# Decomposing a linear map $k^{\oplus n}\rightarrow k^{\oplus m}$ into direct sum of $1$ and $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $k$ be a field and $u:k^{\oplus n}\rightarrow k^{\oplus m}$ be a linear map. I want to decompose $u$ into a direct sum of maps of the following form:

1. $k\xrightarrow{1}k$,
2. $k\rightarrow 0$,
3. $0\rightarrow k$.

It's clear that there exists bases of $k^{\oplus n}$ and $k^{\oplus m}$ for which the matrix $M(u)$ w.r.t. these bases is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r$ is the rank of $u$. I can read the decomposition I am looking for, from this matrix: there should be $r$-many $k\xrightarrow{1}k$ maps, $(n-r)$ many $k\rightarrow 0$ maps, and finally $(m-r)$ many $0\rightarrow k$ maps. I am having difficulty justfying this reading of the matrix.

Let $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ and $(f_j)_{1\leq j\leq m}$ be the bases from which we derived $M(u)$. Observe that by construction $u(e_i)=f_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$. Clearly for every $\ell\in[1,r]$, we have a map $k\cong ke_\ell\rightarrow kf_\ell\cong k$ which is equal to $1$. For every $\ell\in[r+1,n]$, we have a map $k\cong ke_\ell\rightarrow0$. Finally for every $i\in[n+1,m+n-r]$, we have a map $0\rightarrow kf_\ell$.

Is there a way to reexpress this justification, perhaps more formally? i.e. is there a theorem or proposition that captures what I have done here?

It seems to me that what I have done is something like enumerating the bases back-to-back; removing the $f_\ell$ for $\ell\in[1,r]$; partitioning this list; finally, associating maps to these partitions. However, why should the maps be associated in exactly the way I have done? i.e. how can we connect the partitioning of $[1,m+n-r]$ into $[1,r],[r+1,n],[n+1,m+n-r]$ with the number of maps $k\rightarrow k$, $k\rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow k$, in a natural way?

Comment: How about $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$ how would you diagonalize/decompose that?

Comment: @Testcase That would reduce to decomposing $I_2$ which is the direct sum $(k\xrightarrow{1} k)\oplus(k\xrightarrow{1}k)$. Not sure what "diagonalizing" means here